# XPATH not working ns2:namespace preifix not defined error

Tags: xml, xpath, mule, xslt-1.0, mule-studio

Hi am trying to extract the value of UniqueID using the xpath /ns0:Start/ns0:Area/ns0:Test/ns0:Identifier/ns2:UniqueID  but its not working pls help me i need normal xpath as well as an MEL command

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:Start xmlns:ns0="http://www.example.com/xmlns/9/Test">
  <ns0:Area>
    <ns0:Test>
      <ns0:Identifier>
        <ns2:UniqueID xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.com/xmlns/9/foundation">123456</ns2:UniqueID>
      </ns0:Identifier>
    </ns0:Test>
    <ns0:Test>
      <ns0:Identifier>
        <ns2:ExternalOrderID xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.com/xmlns/9/foundation">external</ns2:ExternalOrderID>
      </ns0:Identifier>
      <ns0:Info>
        <ns0:Status>st</ns0:Status>
      </ns0:Info>
    </ns0:Test>
  </ns0:Area>
</ns0:Start>
```

Comment: You need to tell your XPath code what your prefixes mean - there is no requirement or assumption that the prefixes used in an XPath expression are the same prefixes that are used within the XML document - i.e. you might use `exf` for the `http://www.example.com/xmlns/9/foundation` namespace.

Comment: can u show me how to write a xpath for this

Comment: I'm not familiar with your tool but I've put an example in an online tester [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/34d0d929066d5181a5f1aa71acf04068) - as you can see, I've deliberately used different prefixes to show that they don't matter - only the namespace URIs do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Victor said you need to use `mulexml:namespace-manager` for name space :-

Try the following :-

```
<mulexml:namespace-manager includeConfigNamespaces="true">
    <mulexml:namespace prefix="ns0" uri="http://www.example.com/xmlns/9/Test"/>
    <mulexml:namespace prefix="ns2" uri="http://www.example.com/xmlns/9/foundation"/>
</mulexml:namespace-manager>
```

Then use the following Xpath to retrieve **UniqueID** :- `#[xpath('//ns0:Start/ns0:Area/ns0:Test/ns0:Identifier/ns2:UniqueID').text]`

and **ExternalOrderID** :- `#[xpath('//ns0:Start/ns0:Area/ns0:Test/ns0:Identifier/ns2:ExternalOrderID').text]`

This will work :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [name space manager](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/XML+Namespaces):

```
<mulexml:namespace-manager includeConfigNamespaces="true">
    <mulexml:namespace prefix="foo" uri="http://foo.com"/>
</mulexml:namespace-manager>
```